# Space-Hierarchy Theorem in Theoretical CS

Tags: computer-science, proof-explanation, turing-machines

Sipser has a proof this theorem that goes like this:

$$D = \text{"On input } w$$

$$1. \text{Let } n \text{ be the length of } w$$

$$2. \text{Compute } f(n) \\ \text{using space constructibility and mark off this much tape. If later stages ever attempt to use more, } reject$$

$$3. \text{If } w \text{ is not of the form } <M>10^* \text{ for some TM } M, reject.$$

$$4. \text{Simulate } M \text{ on } w \text{ while counting the number of steps used in the simulate. If the count ever exceeds } 2^{f(n)}, reject\text{"}.$$

$$5. \text{If } M \text{ accepts,} reject. \text{If } M \text{ rejects}, accept.$$

So I see get the contradiction if we say that some Turing Machine $M$ decides the language $A$, the language that is decided by $D$, which runs in $o(f(n))$ space.

But what happens when you run $D$ on itself . Doesn't $5$ give you a contradiction? If $D$ accepts, reject, and if $D$ rejects, accept. So wouldn't you get a contradiction assuming that following TM $D$ is a decider of $A$?

The theorem that we're trying to prove is the Space-Time hierarchy. That is, there is a Language A that is decided by TM $M$ $\in$ space (O(f(n)) but not o(f(n)). see:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem

see: https://books.google.com/books?id=1aMKAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA364&lpg=PA364&dq=space+hierarchy+theorem+proof+sipser&source=bl&ots=iDVTiKQedO&sig=ZVNVZ7Gkgp0y77FUcl66gvyTUfs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj81bbf4ZDLAhVFqB4KHabuCr44ChDoAQg7MAQ#v=onepage&q=space%20hierarchy%20theorem%20proof%20sipser&f=false pg 366

Comment: "Sipper" $\to$ "Sipser" ? Also, a link to the statement of the theorem (or better, writing the statement here) would be appreciated. ([Lemma 6 of these lecture notes, I assume](http://theory.stanford.edu/~trevisan/cs172/noteh.pdf)?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Trying to figure out which theorem you are referring to; in any case, the answer below is only based on what you wrote in your question, i.e. the outline of the proof of this theorem, without the corresponding statement, which I assume is the Space Hirerarchy Theorem ([Theorem 2 in these notes](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~luca/cs172/noteh.pdf)).*

If you reach Step 4, the input $w\in\{0,1\}^\ast$ is of the form $w=\langle M \rangle x$ for some valid Turing Machine $M$ and $x\in\in\{0,1\}^\ast$.

Step 4 then runs $M$ on $w$ **within the bound of $t$ time steps**. Your question is: *what if $M=D$?*. But this is still valid: then you simulate the execution of $M=D$ on input $w$. Your issue is  "what if we reach Step 5": but that will not happen.

In Step 4, you get to simulate $D$ on $w$, which costs some number of steps. Then in the simulation, you also starts to simulate (within the simulation) another execution of $D$ on $w$, etc. At each such "subsimulation," whose starting costs at least a few time steps in the original run of $D$, you start a new simulation in step 4.

In other terms, Step 4 causes (the very first execution of) $D$ to loop. So Step 4 of the "original simulation" will run out of time (reach the bound $t$) and reject. Nothing ever reaches Step 5.

Comment: I'm not seeing this. First, Step 4 in Sipser is run $M$ on $w$. Why are we changing the algorithm? I don't know if this is Lemma 6 of the lecture notes or not. Are we not getting the contradiction because are saying $M$ runs on $x$ and $D$ runs on $w$?

Comment: Can you please give a **statement** of the theorem that is supposed to be proven? Right now, I'm trying to answered your question while being half-blinded. Sipser has proven many things, and even then proofs of a single theorem are not always written the same way... where is your proof coming from? What book or lecture notes are you taking it from?

Comment: @lars  saw you added a link to the Google Book. Will refer to it, but the statement of the theorem is still not available -- only the proof... can you provide the statement as well?

Comment: @lars See my edit.

Comment: Just a clarification: $D$ is not in Language $A$ but it is a decider of $A$?

Comment: Yes -- $D$ is a machine that decides $A$ (by definition of $A$). There is no assumption (and there is a priori no reason for that) that $\langle D\rangle \in A$.